# Automatic Page Breaking for listings

Tags: floats, listings

I would like the code listings (i.e `\begin{listing} code \end{listing}`) to automatically break at new pages. This happens by default, however the code listing ends up on a different subsection sometimes.

If I use the `float` package I can get the code listing to appear where I want it to be, but the downside is that there is no automatic page breaking.

What are my options?

**UPDATE** :

My problem was because of using the `minted` package inside a `listing`. The solution to my problem was found here:
https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/104

Comment: You only have two choices (a) leave it in place, aka allowing page breaks or (b) having it float, thus only a single page is available. Do you mind explaining what you mean by: _This happens by default, however the code listing ends up on a different subsection sometimes._ ? that does not make sense for non-floats

Comment: @daleif I do not know why but if I do not use the `float` package the code listing can end up in a different section sometimes. I think this happens when there is not enough space to place the listing in the same page.